# changes made in business object universe designer tool in my system are not reflected in business objects for other users

Tags: designer, business-objects

I am adding an object in my Business Object Universe designer tool and that object in visible to me in my business object and in the reports.
But other users are not able to see the changes.
Kindly help me so that my changes will be visible to other users as well.

Comment: Any suggetsions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Already mentioned that changes made in business objects universe are not visble to other users.

Comment: @JavaGirl 3 things 1) confirm they are going to the same path and infact accessing the "Same" universe.  2) confirm they have logged out and back into business objects Following your update. 3) Confirm object has the proper access level (*public?*)  If not public, then do other users have the right security to access the object?

Comment: @xQbert 1)yes they are using same universe in their system 2)yes the re-logged in and checked 3)where can i check the  access level,could you please assist, also where can i check users security. we all have got same business objects set up done in all the users as that of mine.

Comment: Navigate to and Select the object in UDT which is missing. right click the object.  From the popup select Object properties.  From the popup, select the advanced tab.  If the Security Access level is set to public, I'd think it would be fine unless you have a weird security setup with deny all unless granted.  If it's not public, ensure the users have been assigned rights equal to or greater than the required right.

Comment: Then in CMC under universes select the correct universe, right click and select universe security.  Ensure the requested users have the same object level security you do.  Depending on how your security model is setup this could be straight forward or rather complex.

Comment: The only way I know of for objects to be hidden from another user within the universe is controlled via the object level security.  So if it's not my above approach checking to see what level of security is assigned to the new objects  and what level the users have in the universe.  I'm out of ideas...  You could check an existing object which you know they have access to within the universe for it's security level and ensure the new objects have the same security; provided it's business appropriate to do so.

Comment: in a prior comment I said ensure they have the same security you do... I should curtail that by saying only if it's appropriate to do so.  More info on Object Level Security form a quick Google Search: https://dwbicastle.com/2017/01/11/object-level-security-in-sap-bo-universe-designer/